# How to fix the error " 'id': Select a valid choice" on Modelformset validation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Modelformset that raises this validation error on submission:

> {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the
>   available choices.']}

This error appears the same number of times as objects in my queryset, which is:

```
qs = Task.objects.filter(property=property)
```

Over the last few days I have been trying to fix this. I've read a lot of other similar posts and tried different solutions but none of them worked for me.

**My formset can be seen here:**

```
def add_taskcheck(request, property_pk, pk):
    property = get_object_or_404(Property, pk=property_pk)
    pcheck = get_object_or_404(Propertycheck, pk=pk)
    qs = Task.objects.filter(property=property)
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(property=property_pk)

    TaskCheckFormset = modelformset_factory(TaskCheck, form=TaskCheckForm, fields=('status','image','notes'), extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = TaskCheckFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=qs)
        print(formset.errors)
        if formset.is_valid():
            taskcheck = formset.save(commit=False)
            taskcheck.property_check=pcheck.id
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('propertycheck:details', args=[pk]))
    else:
        formset = TaskCheckFormset(queryset=qs)

    context = {
        'title':"Add Property Check",
        'task':tasks,
        'reference':property_pk,
        'formset':formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'propertycheck/add-taskcheck.html', context)
```

**And my form:**

```
class TaskCheckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    status = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TaskStatus.objects.all(), to_field_name="name", widget=forms.Select(attrs={
    'class':'form-control custom-select',
    'id':'type',
    }))
    image = ...
    notes = ...

    class Meta:
        model = TaskCheck
        fields = ('status','image','notes')
```

**And finally my models:**

```
class TaskCheck(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(TaskStatus)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='task_check', blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    property_check = models.ForeignKey(Propertycheck)

class Task(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    property = models.ManyToManyField(Property)
```

I already know that the problem is not related to **'status'** field. Actually I believe that this is related to the **'task'** field. I've also added the `{{ form.id }}` to template, as I've seen on some other questions.

**For reference, my template:**

```
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
{{ form.id }}
<div class="form-group">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ form.instance.task }}</h5>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="pname">Status</label>
            {{ form.status }}
            {{ form.status.errors }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="pname">Image</label>
            {{ form.image }}
            {{ form.image.errors }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="pname">Notes</label>
            {{ form.notes }}
            {{ form.notes.errors }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

--------**UPDATE**------------

From Oleg's answer I changed my formset validation.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = TaskCheckFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=qs)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                # do something with instance
                instance.property_check=pcheck.id
                instance.save()
```

Comment: I am just guessing here but can you try removing **"id": "type"** from to_attrs of the widget assigned to your status field ?

Comment: @ruhaib the "id":"type" is to reference a CSS id on my form. I've tried, no differences.. thanks!

Comment: It could be because "task" field is missing from your TaskCheckForm and on model task.ForeignKey does not have "null=True". can you try adding "task" to your TaskCheckForm fields ?

Comment: This is a very general default error message in django.forms.models or in django.forms.fields. It is probably necessary to write a traceback of that exception to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue raised because of different models used in ModelFormSet and QuerySet.
The issues can be solved by using:

```
property = get_object_or_404(Property, pk=property_pk)
pcheck = get_object_or_404(Propertycheck, pk=pk)
qs = Task.objects.filter(property=property)
category = qs.values('category').distinct()
TaskCheckFormset = formset_factory(TaskCheckForm,extra=len(qs))

formset = TaskCheckFormset()
    for i in range(len(qs)):
        formset.forms[i].initial['task']=qs[i].id
        formset.forms[i].instance.task=qs[i]
        formset.forms[i].instance.property_check=pcheck
        formset.forms[i].initial['property_check']=pcheck.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This error points to **invalid choice in `ModelChoiceField`** that in provided example is ***status*** field of ***TaskCheckForm***.

This is *class level* attribute and is initiated *only* once application starts and `TaskCheckForm` is being imported for the first time.
And its `QuerySet` is resolved only once at start - and it will see present at that time `TaskStatus` objects and never update its choices list for new or deleted items.

To handle relationship fields and other with dynamic queryset [recommended way can be used](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships) - define *empty* QuerySet on field and set it to required one in form's `__init__` method:

```
    status = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TaskStatus.objects.none(), to_field_name="name", widget=...)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['status'].queryset = TaskStatus.objects.all()
```

---

Other potential problem places in code:

- `tasks = Task.objects.filter(property=property_pk)` - will return a list of results. But later in code is assigned to `task` variable in template which may expect (but may be it is ok and it expects list) single item. You can use `tasks = Task.objects.filter(property=property_pk).first()` instead.
- `taskcheck = formset.save(commit=False)` - first, it returns a list of items (because it is `formset` to act on a set of forms), so in order to add `property_check` attribute to items you need to iterate over result [like in example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset); second - `commit=False` means instances will not be saved, which is ok as some additional attribute is set later, but no `instance.save()` is called afterwards - so still no changes will be saved.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I added the `__init__` function on my form but the error remains. What I have tried again is removing the status field from everywhere, and it still gives the same error. That is why I think the problem is not related to the status, anyway I'll use like you said. The `tasks = Task.objects.filter(property=property_pk)`is the same as qs queryset, I'll might delete it.

Comment: Also, why form and formset are for `TaskCheck` but queryset is for `Task`?

Comment: That is because of my dependencies. TaskCheck's purpose is to save the status of a specific Task, and a Task can be related to a specific property. So my queryset goes  through the tasks of the instance property. I'll update my question and insert the task model for better understanding.

Comment: `formset = TaskCheckFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=qs)` - formset uses `TaskCheck` model but `qs` is for `Task` model. This may cause incompatible fields etc.

Comment: I’ll try to create a TaskCheck query that returns the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query is not correct. You are doing

```
qs = Task.objects.filter(property=property)
```

It should be like this-

```
qs = Task.objects.filter(property__id=property.id)
```

Or you can do like this:

```
qs = Task.objects.filter(property__in=[property_pk])
```

Here `property` is a many to many field. Your query looks like searching foreign key.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately my problem is not related to that. The formset is not valid, so it doesn't even reach that point. Anyway I made those changes.